# package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist after setting class path

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to learn Java DataBase.

When I try to load driver by `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`; it works fine ( Mean no Exception thrown ) But when I tried to register it using `DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());` I got the following exception.

```
DriveManage.java:9: error: package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
                                                                           ^
1 error
```

I'm using ojdbc6.jar that I have in the following directory.
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\ext

After searching I found that I need to set class path too. I set `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\ext` to Environment Variables. But It still not working. Any Solution?

As Advised in comment to use `.jar` in class path.

I go to control panel then edit the Computer Environment Variables and there add this link after `;` `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\ext\ojdbc6.jar` but it still not working. I also tried `C:\app\OracleHome\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar` but it also not working.

Comment: check your lib folder inside web-inf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect oracle 11g database using java 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149626/connect-oracle-11g-database-using-java-1-7)

Comment: @manikantgautam where is that folder?

Comment: Add the jar not the folder containing the jar.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch adding that still not working.

Comment: Please edit your question to include **how** you have set your classpath; because that appears to be what is wrong.